# Cannot create a country list properly from feature of imported data

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am a beginner of Google Earth Engine, trying to extract nightlights value by country and year in the African continent for my dissertation.

As a prerequisite for doing so, I am trying to make a list of African countries so that I can extract data, but it does not cover whole countries. In fact, some countries(Gambia, Democratic Republic of Congo, Congo, and Ivory Coast) are not covered as the image indicates.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZwnt.png)
In order to fix the issue, I have checked the value in imported data, but name itself seems to be OK. I am not quite sure why I can not extract data by country even if naming is accurate. Please help me fix this issue and offer better and sophisticated solutions. Thx

This is the link of code

[Blockquote](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmjk22001%2FNightLight_Africa%3AAfrican%20NightLights%2FUntitledFile)

This is the link of geological data of African countries.
[enter link description here](https://geoportal.icpac.net/layers/geonode:afr_g2014_2013_0)

```js
Map.centerObject(table,2);
Map.addLayer(table,{},"Africa");

var countryList = ["Algeria", "Angola", "Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Comoros", "Republic of the Congo", " CÃ´te d'Ivoire", "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Djibouti", "Egypt", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Ethiopia", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Ghana", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mali", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Rwanda", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", "South Sudan", "Sudan", "Swaziland", "Togo", "Tunisia", "Uganda", "Tanzania", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"];
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017').filter(ee.Filter.inList("country_na", countryList));

Map.addLayer(countries,{},"countries of interest");

Map.centerObject(countries,2);

// import the nightlight image collection


// set the start and end dates
var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(2014,1,1);
var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(2014,12,31);
 
// filter for the period of interest
var nightlights2014 = nightlight.filterDate(start,end);
// take the mean note that this operation transforms the image collection into an image
nightlights2014 = ee.Image(nightlights2014.mean());
// select the avg_rad band
nightlights2014 = nightlights2014.select("avg_rad");
// clip for the area of interest
nightlights2014 = nightlights2014.clip(countries);
Map.addLayer(nightlights2014,{min:0,max:10,palette:['000000','700000','808080','FFFF00','ffffff','ffffff','ffffff']},"nightlights 2014");

//create a variable for data export
var data_export_2014 = nightlights2014.reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  collection: countries,
  scale: 450
});

//execution of data export
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection:data_export_2014,
  description: "nightlights2014",
  folder: "nightlights_Africa",
  selectors: (["mean"])
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your names are not consistent with the values of the `countries_na` property. For instance, Democratic Republic of the Congo is abbreviated as Dem Rep of the Congo in that dataset. Easiest solution may be to load the entire country dataset as a map layer and use the inspector to find the correct name. Alternatively, you could filter to all countries in Africa using

```js
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.eq("wld_rgn", "Africa"));
```

Comment: Thank you Jesse for your quick answer and more easier solution! Best Regards